# Reading comma in content of csv file (E.g. $1,23,456)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, csv

Using C# program I am reading CSV File with value like (Name, Salary, Age)  (A,  $1,200, 27) (B, 2300, 27)

In the header  row there are three columns. I want to validate that the number of columns in data rows is also three. (C, 28) should be an invalid file.

Currently I am doing this by counting the number of commas. But when the content itself is having comma  ($1,200), this logic is failing.  How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Use the right tool for the job: [A CSV parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507498/reading-csv-file/3508572#3508572)

Comment: Its homework or something similar? If not there are libraries you can use in commercial applications without paying.

Comment: What do you mean, third party? That's in the .NET BCL. Or is this perhaps a homeword assignment?

Comment: If the file is actually formatted like that, it isn't valid CSV. Please copy and paste an actual sample from your file in your question and format it using Ctrl-K.

Answer (score 1):

Use library for reading csv files. Why are you wrintg it on yourown when someone already did it for you?. Last time i was reading csv i used `CsvHelper`.

Answer (score 0):

As a fast answer why don you split by (", ")

```
var s  = "Name, Salary, Age";
var t = "A, $1,200, 27";
var x = "B, 2300, 27";

string[] stringSeparators = new string[] {", "};

s.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None).Dump();
t.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None).Dump();
x.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None).Dump();
```

Not the best solution but it's one that fits....

As was commented by @Tim Pietzcker it's not a valid csv file....

Anyway....

Comment: This might work for names like `A` and `B`, but not names like `Smith, Bob`.

Comment: Dump(), method is an Extension method added by Linqpad

Answer (score 0):

Could you perhaps do this?...where fileLine would be "A, $1,200, 27". This is assuming that each column is delineated by a comma then a space.

```
        int lastCommaIdx = fileLine.LastIndexOf(",");
        string agePart = fileLine.Substring(lastCommaIdx + 1, fileLine.Length - (lastCommaIdx + 1)).Trim();
        int age = Convert.ToInt32(agePart);

        fileLine = fileLine.Substring(0, lastCommaIdx);
        int dollarIdx = fileLine.LastIndexOf("$");
        string salary = fileLine.Substring(dollarIdx, fileLine.Length - dollarIdx).Trim();

        string name = fileLine.Substring(0, dollarIdx).Trim().TrimEnd(new char[1] { ',' });

        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Name={0}, Salary={1}, Age={2}", name, salary, age));
```

Comment: What about names like `Smith, Bob`?