# how to split the line in the text file

Tags: c#, split

Text File:

```
$3.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,L55894M8,$3.00,0.00,0.00,2.00,L55894M9
```

How do I split the line and get the serial number like `L55894M8` and `L55894M9`?

Comment: Are the serial numbers always at the same point in the line?  Do they always occur after the 4th comma and 9th comma?

Comment: Will your serial always start with L like L55894M8 and L55894M9

Comment: Please don't prefix your questions with "C#: ". That's what tags are for.

Comment: if you google "c# split line" you get the answer.

Comment: the serial number always different. But the serial number always at the same point in the line

Comment: That's a CSV file.  You can parse CSV files in .NET as using tools from [Reading CSV files using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3507498/3744182).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sample you means want to get the words in index of (  4 , 9 , 14 .... )

And the five words as a party .

So you can try this way.....

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string strSample = "$3.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,L55894M8,$3.00,0.00,0.00,2.00,L55894M9";
        var result = from p in strSample.Split(',').Select((v, i) => new { Index = i, Value = v })
                     where p.Index % 5 == 4
                     select p.Value;

        foreach (var r in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(r);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the data that appears after the 4th comma and 9th comma, you would want to do:

```
var pieces = line.Split(',');
var serial1 = line[3];
var serial2 = line[8];
```

Edit: Upon further reflection, it appears your file has records that begin with $ and end with the next record. If you want these records, along with the serial number (which appears to be the last field) you can do:

```
var records = line.TrimStart('$').Split('$');
var recordObjects = records.Select(r => new { Line = r, Serial = r.TrimEnd(',').Split(',').Last() });
```

Answer (score 0):

if the file is in a string you can use the string's `.split(',')` method then check each element of the resulting array. Or grab every 5th element if that pattern of data is seen throughout.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "$3.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,L55894M8,$3.00,0.00,0.00,2.00,L55894M9";
var fieldArray = str.Split(new[] { ',' });
var serial1 = fieldArray[4];  // "L55894M8"
var serial2 = fieldArray[9];  // "L55894M9"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try regular expression.

```
 string str = "$3.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,L55894M8,$3.00,0.00,0.00,2.00,L55894M9";
 string pat = @"L[\w]+";

 MatchCollection ar=  Regex.Matches(str, pat);

 foreach (var t in ar)
     Console.WriteLine(t);
```