# Replacing CSV delimitators

Tags: c#

I'm trying to replace a csv delimiters using regular expression, but can't get my head around the parameters.

Sample text:

```
2136203,"asd asdd","17 - Alpha","13 - Scsdeori Colsden",05.04.12,A,255659,"VOSDEFER ADEDEAN","SER.HDEDEA NR 52 BL - SC - AP -, PDEXTA, AEDD, CP 312337",RO26A34498,20.04.12,,12.04.12,"Confsdare"
```

I want to split the string like this:

1. 2136203
2. asd asdd
3. 17 - Alpha
4. 13 - Scsdeori Colsden
5. 05.04.12
6. A
7. 255659
8. VOSDEFER ADEDEAN
9. SER.HDEDEA NR 52 BL - SC - AP -, PDEXTA, AEDD, CP 312337
10. RO26A34498
11. 20.04.12
12. 1. 12.04.12
13. Confsdare

Comment: What is the question? Replace which delimiters with what?

Comment: Explain your problem and also what do you actually want to achieve

Comment: I want to replace the csv text qualifier and delimitators with "|"

Answer (score 1):

Use the example on the top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507498/reading-csv-file) to parse the file.

This turns your file into a `string[]` you read one row at a time.

Then write out a new file with the format you need.