# Using LINQ for CSV data

Tags: c#, linq, csv

My code works great, as long as there aren't any commas in the data.

```
IEnumerable<Account> AccountItems = from line in File.ReadAllLines(filePath).Skip(1)
                let columns = line.Split(',')
                select new Account
                {
                    AccountName = columns[0],
                    BKAccountID = columns[1],
                    Brand = columns[2],
                    FirstOE = columns[3],
                    LastOE = columns[4]
                };
```

But the output includes data with commas, and wraps the data in double quotes when there is a comma in the data.  I'm not sure if I can still use LINQ to do this.

```
Acme Health Care,{C2F9A7DD-0000-0000-0000-8B06859016AD},"Data With, LLC",2/4/2013,2/18/2013
```

Comment: Regex here would get very complex very quickly. It's better to use the .NET libraries to handle this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at this question:
[Reading CSV files using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507498/reading-csv-file)

```
TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(@"c:\temp\test.csv");
parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
parser.SetDelimiters(",");
while (!parser.EndOfData) 
{
    //Processing row
    string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
    foreach (string field in fields) 
    {
        //TODO: Process field
    }
}
parser.Close();
```

No need to reinvent the wheel when .NET can hold your hand.