# Split string separated by comma but without splitting double value

Tags: c#

Here's my string I got from a csv:

```
string input = "Volume,447,\"4,325\",142,144";
```

what I want in my array lines:

```
447
4,325
142
144
```

What I tried:

```
string[] volumes;
if (input.Contains(",\"")) // if they're all double value, it works
     volumes = input.Split(new[] {",\""}, StringSplitOptions.None);
else
     volumes= input.Split(','); // if they're all integer value it works
else
     // what to do if they have both double and integer?
```

Comment: Sounds like you could do with a decent CSV parser... I wouldn't bother trying to roll your own.

Comment: If you got this string from JSON, why don't you deserialize it completely instead of parsing string? Or maybe it will be simplier, if you provide raw JSON for us

Comment: @Uriil omg, sorry, my string comes from a csv, not from a json

Comment: @JonSkeet yeah, you're right. I'm gonna do that.

Comment: @Gui: Here's a simple but efficient that also supports quoting characters: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader You should avoid the same field- and decimal-separator.

Comment: I ended up using this solution, it's working great.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507498/reading-csv-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to reference Microsoft.VisualBasic (event if you code in C#) to compile the following code.

```
    private string[] ParseCsv(string line)
    {
        var parser = new TextFieldParser(new StringReader(line));
        parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
        parser.SetDelimiters(",");
        while (!parser.EndOfData)
        {
            return parser.ReadFields();
        }
        parser.Close();
        return new string[0];
    }
```

Comment: [TextFieldParser class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx)