# Convert CSV with unknown schema to XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, csv

I am reading a CSV file and converting it into XML format.

```
   public static string ConvertCSVToXML(string filePath)
   {
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
        XElement xml = new XElement("RootElement",
                from str in lines
                let col = str.Split(',')
                select new XElement("Item",
                    new XElement("Column1", col[0]),
                    new XElement("Column2", col[1]),
                    new XElement("Column3", col[2]),
                    new XElement("Column4", col[3])
                    )
            );
        return xml.ToString();
   }
```

Here we know the header of the CSV so it works. 
How to convert it when schema of the CSV is undefined?
File contains header row but it is not known how many headers and what are header titles.

Comment: So, is there anything defined about the CSV file?

Comment: Yes. That it is a valid file!

Comment: You mean [this valid](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180)? As in *"there is no formal specification in existence"*?

Comment: Yes, that type of file.

Comment: A little sample: what is your expected result for the following csv file: `1,2;3,4`?

Comment: I have file with header line

Comment: Then you have additional constraints defined on your CSV format and you need to state them in the question if you want answers!

Comment: Check this out for a starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3508572/5265292

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems seem much bigger till it is not solved!

However it was possible using same linq to xml query with some modifications. For a moment I forgot that I can also access the index in linq select query,

```
    public static string ConvertCSVToXML(string filePath, char seperator)
    {
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
        var headers = lines[0].Split(seperator);
        XElement xml = new XElement("RootElement",
                            lines.Select(line => new XElement("Item",
                                line.Split(seperator).Select((column, index) => 
                                   new XElement(headers[index], column))
                            ))
                        );
        return xml.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Just be careful with this solution, as it will not work if the data itself contains commas or line breaks.

Comment: @user2366842, Yes indeed! As I said it will work if file is valid. If data itself 
 contains seperator it will consider as seperate data value. But I had not used static comma as separator in fact.

Answer (score 0):

With [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL/) - an open source ETL framework, you can do it easily

For a sample CSV (users.csv) file below

```
Id,Name
1,Washington
2,Lincoln
```

Code below shows how to read and produce XML file

```
using (var reader = new ChoCSVReader("users.csv").WithFirstLineHeader())
{
    using (var writer = new ChoXmlWriter("users.xml").WithXPath("Emps/Emp"))
        writer.Write(reader);
}
```

The output XML file look as below

```
<Emps>
  <Emp>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Name>Washington</Name>
  </Emp>
  <Emp>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Name>Lincoln</Name>
  </Emp>
</Emps>
```

Hope this helps.

Disclosure: I'm the author of this library

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Linq to sql is working for my purpose so I would not like to add new library reference. But it will definately be helpful to someone!