# c# identify a column data type dynamically

Tags: c#, csv, compare

I am working on an application which will compare two datasets. This will take two .csv files and compare the data between them. I have to read the .csv files and compare the file field to field. Now I don't want to waste time by comparing columns that are already matching when summed. currently, I am storing the list as DataTable. How can I find the field datatype if it is an integer or date or decimal or string?

Is there an easy way to do or a library available?

Please help.

Comment: Any framework is going to make you define what the data type should be for the column.

For an example of what could be done check out this question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507498/reading-csv-files-using-c-sharp

Comment: No, not really. if a column contains values such as `1, 1, 0, 1` it could be int, float, double, a string or even boolean. if it contains values such as `1.1, 2.3` it could be double or float or maybe simply a string. Basically, everything in a csv is a string unless you know for sure it's something else.

Comment: As Zohar Peled mentioned, I am having a problem to determine if it is int or decimal or float. Also, I can loop through the first record and find by "tryparse" to find the datatype. what if the later record has a decimal or a string in it. should I loop through each record to determine the datatype? Is there a fast and simple way to do it?

Comment: Keep everything as strings. Otherwise you will be forced to make assumptions that might lead you to faulty code.