# importing excel file and utilizing data for unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I try to develop an app using unity for cross platform purpose.

Here is my problem: I have a huge number of images and texts related to each image which I want to import to the app to display. I also want to revise and update these later and, of course, to use them to display as contents for my app.

I figure maybe just using programs such as Excel.

Here is my question: How do I do that? Importing excel files into unity and hopefully update-able in the future?

Comment: why not include everything in the Resources folder or as an asset bundle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are different third party solution including some open source projects

1. [Excel4Unity](https://github.com/joexi/Excel4Unity)
2. [Unity-QuickSheet](https://github.com/kimsama/Unity-QuickSheet)
3. [Excel to Unity Pipeline Tutorial](http://gamedesignstuff.com/excel-to-unity-pipeline/)
4. [Reading CSV files using C# - Q/A at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507498/reading-csv-files-using-c-sharp)
5. [Unity-QuickSheet](http://kimsama.github.io/excel-howto/)
6. [Excel to Unity-Paid solution](http://assets.funnyfacegame.com/?p=13)

Comment: Thanks, You may accept the answer if it solve your problem.