# Remove values from rows under specific columns in csv file

Tags: c#, csv, xslt, data-manipulation

I'm currently trying to remove specific values from rows under specific columns in a CSV-file.

Whats the best way of doing this?

Is it to use a XSLT map file in the code or doing this only by code? (Using c#)

What I want to do is this:

BEFORE MANIPULATION:

```
 id, name, email, phoneNumber, dob 
 1,John Doe,JohnDoe@mail.com,123456789,1988-08-08
 2,Jane Doe,JaneDoe@mail.com,987654321,1987-07-07
```

AFTER MANIPULATION:

```
 id, name, email, phoneNumber, dob 
 1,John Doe,,,1988-08-08 
 2,Jane Doe,,,1987-07-07
```

As you can see "email" and "phoneNumber" is gone

Comment: Please edit your question and show us the code you are currently working with and describe any issues you are having with that code.

Comment: XSLT is really designed for converting XML files. Whilst not impossible to handle CSV files, you are really better off doing it by code. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507498/reading-csv-files-using-c-sharp for one example.

Comment: It's not difficult, so I would do with code. There might be some tool that would let you do it with less code, but the time taken to learn it would remove any benefit  (and a future maintainer would probably rewrite it from scratch). Just read the file into a set of variables, one line at a time. Clear any variables you want, and write them to a new file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use C# without any libs to separate and joint csv strings. it's easier than use XLST. As sample:

```
 String csv = "1,John Doe,JohnDoe@mail.com,123456789,1988-08-08";
 String[] csvList = csv.Split(',');
 csvList[2] = "";
 csvList[3] = "";
 csv = String.Join(",", csvList);
```

Comment: This was exactly what i was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Best way very much depends on personal preferences. For me the best way would be  to use sed. Assuming your data is in `data.csv` file:

```
cat data.csv | sed '2,$ s/\([^,]*\),\(.[^,]*\),\(.[^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\)/\1,\2,,,\5/' > output.csv
```