# Double parse with decimals C#

Tags: c#, windows, decimal

I have a csv reader class that reads a bunch of .csv files [Save the content of several csv files into a searchable array C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60554595/save-the-content-of-several-csv-files-into-a-searchable-array-c-sharp)

In these files I have values with decimals (saved as strings) that I want to `prase` from a `string` to a `double`:

```
public double GetVal(string filename, int row, int column)
        {
            filename = filename + ".csv";
            try
            {
                string returnstring = _dictionary[filename][row][column];
                double returnval = double.Parse(returnstring);
                return returnval;
            }
            catch //if the value cannot be converted to a double, for instance if it is a header
            {
                return Double.NaN;
            }
        }
```

This works very well on my own computer with English languages settings (Windows 10). However when I try to `prase` a `returnstring` like `1810.5` I get an error when using Swedish languages settings on other machines. In the Swedish settings we use `,` instead of `.` as a marker for decimals. Is there any way to make C# understand that `.` is always used for decimals no matter the Windows language settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define the culture you want to use to parse the string. Try this:

```
double.Parse(returnString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

This uses the [`double.Parse` overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.parse?view=netframework-4.8#System_Double_Parse_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_) that takes a `CultureInfo` as second argument and passes `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` which uses a `.` as decimal point.

Comment: Seems to work if I include `using System.Globalization;`, but need to test it on my Swedish system tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`double.Parse(String, IFormatProvider)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.parse?view=netframework-4.8#System_Double_Parse_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_) overload, and pass an appropriate `CultureInfo` object for the second parameter. In your case, you probably want:

```cs
double.Parse(returnstring, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```