# How to read the content of multiple csv files in a list in c#

Tags: c#, csv, readline

I want to read in the content of multiple csv files in a list and use this list to split the contents in a datagridview. The problem is that with this code I only get the filenames but not the content of the files. How do I read in the content?

Below you can see the code.

```cs
public List<string> GetFileList(string strFilePath, bool SubFolders)
{
    List<string> FileArray = new List<string>();

    var fileContent = string.Empty;
    var filePath = string.Empty;

    using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "C:\\Users\\blabla\\Desktop\\folder\\files";
        openFileDialog.Filter = "csv files (*.csv)|*.csv|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 2;
        openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
        openFileDialog.Multiselect = true;

        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                string[] Files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(strFilePath);
                string[] Folders = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(strFilePath);

                for (int i = 0; i < Files.Length; i++)
                {
                    FileArray.Add(Files[i].ToString());
                }

                if (SubFolders == true)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < Files.Length; i++)
                    {
                        FileArray.AddRange(GetFileList(Folders[i], SubFolders));
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                throw (Ex);
            }
            return FileArray;
        }
        return FileArray;
    }
}
```

I expected to use the contents in FileArray for a datagridview, but I only get the filenames.
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading CSV files using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507498/reading-csv-files-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting only file names because you are reading only file names :)

You need to use

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Files[i].ToString());
FileArray.AddRange(lines)
```

in your program.

> MSDN states:
>
> **System.IO.Directory.GetFiles**
>
> Returns the names of files that meet
>
> specified criteria.

So you need to open each and every file, read all content from it and add it to the return variable.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to import namespace Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO? If yes, then you might have a look at the TextFieldParser class (see [microsoft documentation and example](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser?view=netframework-4.8)). This is a very comfortable class to import CSV files and read them line by line. In a loop you could then fill your target collection with the corresponding data.

Comment: If you're reading CSV files on a line-by-line basis then you're doing it wrong. CSV files are a streaming protocol that should be read with a state machine. Have a read through [Common Format and MIME Type for Comma-Separated Values (CSV) Files](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180)

Comment: Where exactly in your linked text does it say that CSV is a streaming protocol? How will a state machine read the CSV file at the end of the day, if not line by line?

Comment: Have a close look at example 6 in "2.  Definition of the CSV Format." Line breaks can appear in the middle of fields. If you're reading a CSV file line-by-line you'll break fields that contain a line break. A compliant CSV reader will be processing the file one character at a time.

Comment: Ah, ok, then we talked a bit past each other :-) Based on the RFC you're right of course. I meant you can loop line by line through TextFieldParser's output since it can get along with line breaks within fields (if they're correctly enclosed in double quotes). That's what I meant by calling it a comfortable class. But again, your hint is absolutely right that on the lowest level the file should be read character wise (So my second question is ultimately wrong).