# how do i read information from the second column in my csv file, and use the data stored in each row of that column to calculate something?

Tags: c#, csv, calculation

I want to increase my basePremium(=200) by a certain percentage, the percentages are stored in rows of the second column in my csv file. the percentage will be determined by the selection the user makes from a drop-down list that has the values from the first column stored in it.

I want to store this calculation in a  method in a class that I can use in different forms.

```
  public void premiumCalc()
    {

        StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("JobList.csv");

        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            String line = reader.ReadLine();
            String[] values = line.Split(',');
        }
        reader.Close(); //close the csv file
    }
    double basePremium = 200.00;



    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `values[1]` ? Also, I would suggest you use an actual csv reader library

Comment: @cricket_007 where would I add 'values[1]' and what do you mean an actual csv reader library?

Comment: In the loop? After you actually get the array? And I mean something other than a StreamReader. Many lists of ways here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507498/reading-csv-files-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

In somewhat object-oriented approach, you may solve it this way:

1. Create a class containing three properties `PropertyColumn1`,`PropertyColumn2`,`BasePremium`, and `CalculatedPremium`
2. Populate the list with each row from CSV file
3. Loop thru each item and assign the value to `CalculatedPremium` property

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You can try [ExcelDataReader](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExcelDataReader/) library to read your CSV file.
And here is example of method that will return percentage based on user selection:

```
public double GetPercentage(string key)
{
    using (var stream = new FileStream("JobList.csv", FileMode.Open))
    {
        using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateCsvReader(stream))
        {
            while (reader.Read()) 
            {
                var valueColumn1 = reader.GetValue(0)?.ToString();
                if (key == valueColumn1)
                {
                    return double.TryParse(reader.GetValue(1)?.ToString(), out var percentage)
                        ? percentage
                        : 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```