# How i can assign result methods in variable? C#

Tags: c#, .net

Code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace TimeTress
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GetString("../../../../timeline.csv");
            GetString("../../../../people.csv");
        }

        static void GetString(string path)
        {
            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(path))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Файл не найден по пути {Path.GetFullPath(path)}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is necessary that the result should not be simply displayed, but written into two different variables, preferably into the arrays string [] [] or string [], so that you can work with them in the future. File text: timeline: {event_date}; {event_description} people: {Name}; {Date of Birth}; {Date of death}

Comment: `var array1 = File.ReadAllLines("../../../../timeline.csv")` ?

Comment: System.String[] output

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507498/reading-csv-files-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the method's return type to `string[]` or `List<string>` (if you don't know the difference, use Google)

then, instead of:

```
Console.WriteLine(line);
```

create a list and add lines to it:

```
List<string> result = new ListString();
foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(path))
{
    result.Add(line);
}
return line; // or `lines.ToArray()`, if your return type is `string[]`
```

Now you need to think about the return value when the file does not exist. One option would be returning `null`. But that's not good and forces the users (of the method, I mean, the programmers) to check for null result whenever the method is called. A better option in my opinion is *not checking for the existence of the file*. Yes, you heard me right. Let the `FileNotFoundException` be thrown.

For more elaborate ways of processing the CSV file and parsing fields, consult other posts on the internet, including the ones available in StackOverflow

Comment: `var result = GetString("../../../../timeline.csv");` ? I think you need to learn more about basics of computer programming.

Comment: and i need more practices, i'am have experience 1-2 weeks, it's my homework

Answer (score 0):

First, the variable(s) need to be defined before a value can be assigned to the variable(s). This variable definition is done using a statement similar to the following:

`string[] stringArray;`

After defining a variable, it is possible to assign values to the intended variable(s), as shown below:

`stringArray = new string[] { "message one", "message two" };`

Building upon this, if one would like to read through the lines in a text file, assign the lines to an array of strings, and then return a variable containing that array of strings, the following function would be one way to accomplish this:

```
static string[] GetListOfStringsFromTextFile(string filePath)
{
    string[] stringArray;

    if (File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        // ReadAllLines() already returns a string array. No need to loop.
        stringArray = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
    }
    else
    {
        // If file not found, return empty string array as default.
        stringArray = new string[0];
    }
    
    return stringArray;
}
```