# How can I re-write this input/output files so that my input file is a comma delimited file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, csv, console-application

How can I re-write this input/output files so that my input file is a comma delimited file (input.csv)?

Input file (input.csv):

```
Smith,John,87
Doe,Jane,93
Sacramanto,Bob,57
```

I'm a beginner and my teacher says we must use the line.indexOf() function.

```
// constant variables
const string INPUT_FILE = "input.txt";
const string OUTPUT_FILE = "output.txt";

// open the input file
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(INPUT_FILE);

// fields used for input file
string? line = "";

string firstName = "", lastName = "";
double mark = 0;

// variables for calculating average
double total = 0, count = 0, avg = 0;

// read the first line of text from the input file
line = sr.ReadLine();


// continue to read until you reach end of file


while (line != null)
{

string [] values = line.Split(',');

// get firstName
firstName = line;

// read next line & get last name
line = sr.ReadLine();
lastName = line;

// read next line & get mark
line = sr.ReadLine();
mark = Convert.ToDouble(line);

Console.WriteLine(firstName + ' ' + lastName + ": " + mark);

// accumulate 'total' & increment 'count'
total = total + mark;
count++;

// read the next line
line = sr.ReadLine();

}
//close input file
sr.Close();


avg = total / count;
Console.WriteLine("\nClass Average: " + avg);

// open an output file
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(OUTPUT_FILE);

sw.WriteLine(avg);

sw.Close();
```

Comment: Questions that ask "please help me" tend to be looking for highly localized guidance, or in some cases, ongoing or private assistance, which is not suited to our Q&A format. It is also rather vague, and is better replaced with a more specific question. Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).

Comment: You should use the framework class that exists to parse CSV files: `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser`.  See [Reading CSV files using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3508572/3744182).  Actually your question looks to be a duplicate of [Reading CSV files using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3507498/3744182) unless you can be more specific about where you are stuck.  Does your current code not work?  Where do you need help?  See [ask].

Comment: The `IndexOf()` constraint means you are unlikely to get a good answer here, because no self-respecting developer would ever use `IndexOf()` for this when there are perfectly good CSV parsers available on NuGet or built into C#/.Net already.  If nothing else we'd use `Split()`, and even that is pushing it.

Comment: I have found a lot of information that through "strLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null", you can accurately traverse the elements in the collection and then output through the output stream. Many materials do this

Answer (score 0):

I think you made a little bit of confusion between `line` and `values`. `line` contains the actual line, `values` contains the separated values of the single line. You have to read the line once for each loop iteration. Try the code blelow

```
// constant variables
const string INPUT_FILE = "input.txt";
const string OUTPUT_FILE = "output.txt";

// open the input file
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(INPUT_FILE);

// fields used for input file
string? line = "";

string firstName = "", lastName = "";
double mark = 0;

// variables for calculating average
double total = 0, count = 0, avg = 0;

// continue to read until you reach end of file


while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
    // read the first line of text from the input file
    line = sr.ReadLine();

    if (line != null)
    {
        string[] values = line.Split(',');
        if (values.Count() == 3)
        {
            firstName = values[0];
            lastName = values[1];
            mark = double.Parse(values[2]);
            total += mark;
            count++;
        }
    }
}
//close input file
sr.Close();

avg = total / count;
Console.WriteLine("\nClass Average: " + avg);

// open an output file
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(OUTPUT_FILE);

sw.WriteLine(avg);

sw.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap code that reads and writes "IO" with a "try...catch" block so that if there is an error in the program, it can be resolved.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test();
    }

    public static void Test () 
    {
        try
        {
            // constant variables
            const string INPUT_FILE = "input.txt";
            const string OUTPUT_FILE = "output.txt";

            // open the input file
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(INPUT_FILE);

            // fields used for input file
            string? line = "";

            string firstName = "", lastName = "";
            double mark = 0;

            // variables for calculating average
            double total = 0, count = 0, avg = 0;

            // continue to read until you reach end of file

            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] values = line.Split(',');
                firstName = values[0];
                lastName = values[1];
                mark = double.Parse(values[2]);
                count++;

            }

            //close input file
            sr.Close();

            avg = total / count;
            Console.WriteLine("\nClass Average: " + avg);

            // open an output file
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(OUTPUT_FILE);

            sw.WriteLine(avg);

            sw.Flush();

            sw.Close();
        }catch (Exception ex)
        {
             Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
     
    }
```