# read and load json file c#?

Tags: c#, json, load, converters

How can I read my JSON file in my program and load it into my list ?

This is what my "load" method looks like.
My program can also load and display *csv* file therefore in my load method is also code from *csv*.

```cs
public void Load(string path)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Dateiname eingeben, um zu laden.");
    string filename = Console.ReadLine();

    string json = ".json";
    bool o = filename.Contains(json);

    string fullFilePathName = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, filename);
    string fContent = File.ReadAllText(fullFilePathName);

    // Bremen;1200;1.2t\r\nHamburg;500;500kg\r\nBochum;5000;10kg
    liste.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine(fContent);
    string[] datensaetze = fContent.Split("\r\n");
    foreach (string datera in datensaetze)
    {
        if (datera.Length > 0)
        {
            // Format: Bremen;1200;1.2t
            LKW lkw = new LKW();
            if (lkw.Eingabe_CSV(datera) == true)
            {
                liste.Add(lkw);

            }

            else
            {

            }
```

Comment: This does not look like json. More like csv: `// Bremen;1200;1.2t\r\nHamburg;500;500kg\r\nBochum;5000;10kg`

Comment: Numerous tools exist to make [processing JSON **and/or** CSV files easy and hassle free.  Proper research is your friend

Answer (score 0):

Check out: [Reading CSV files using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507498/reading-csv-files-using-c-sharp) for csv files and `System.Text.Json` for [json serialization/deserialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0).

If you just want to split a string of semicolon separated values into a list you can use something like:

```
string data = "Bremen;1200;1.2t\r\nHamburg;500;500kg\r\nBochum;5000;10kg";
var aList = data.Split(';').ToList();
```