# get property name from generic list

Tags: c#

Environment: asp.net fx3.5

given

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
}
```

i have a `List<Product>` collection.

is there a way to get the property names because i want them to be a header row in my csv file that i'm constructing?

so the result i'm looking for is a `string = "ProductId,ProductName,UnitPrice"`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1998049/139698 - I like the following solution but I didn't understand the comments made about possible performance using string builder. so i did some searching and found the following and implemented it: http://www.csharp411.com/c-convert-string-to-stream-and-stream-to-string/   - Was this what the comments were referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`TypeDescriptor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor.aspx) class (which is more efficient than plain reflection):

```
string.Join(",", TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(instance).Select(p => p.Name))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var headers = this.GetType().GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name).Aggregate((p1, p2) => p1 + "," + p2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String.Join(",", typeof(Product).GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name))
```

If you don't want to use Linq, you can just iterate through the PropertyInfo array returned by GetProperties and concatenate the names to a string.